# JPA 1.0 error: The name is not a recognized entity or identifier. Known entity names: []

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, openjpa, jpa-1.0

I am getting following exception while I try to execute simple JPA 1.0 code.
What may be the cause?

```
5453  DevPQRWDPBSSPersist  WARN   [P=351601:O=0:CT] openjpa.Enhance - This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "[class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.markerentry, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Serviceproduct, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Agreementterms, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringattribute, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.marker, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.OfferingpriceadjustmentrelPK, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Serviceoffering, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringassociation, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.OfferingpriceserviceofferingrelPK, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offer, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringpriceadjustmentrel, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringfamily, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringpriceserviceofferingrel, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Serviceproductattribute, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Offeringprice, class com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.db.data.Agreement]".
6563  DevPQRWDPBSSPersist  TRACE  [P=351601:O=0:CT] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1183336072, conn 944453707> executing prepstmnt 152307988 SELECT so.* from DB2INST1.SERVICEOFFERING so where so.ISDELETED = 0 and so.id in (select oa.SERVICEOFFERINGID from DB2INST1.OFFERINGATTRIBUTE oa where oa.SERVICEOFFERINGID = so.id AND oa.name = ? and oa.STRINGVALUE = ? and oa.ISDELETED = 0) [params=(String) productbundleid, (String) attrValue]
7281  DevPQRWDPBSSPersist  TRACE  [P=351601:O=0:CT] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1183336072, conn 944453707> [718 ms] spent
Exception in thread "P=351601:O=0:CT" <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the query filter "SELECT OBJECT(attr) FROM Offeringattribute attr WHERE attr.serviceofferingid IN (:OfferingIds) AND attr.isdeleted = 0". Error message: The name "Offeringattribute" is not a recognized entity or identifier. Known entity names: []
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.exps.AbstractExpressionBuilder.parseException(AbstractExpressionBuilder.java:118)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:180)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.resolveClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:150)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:225)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:195)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateType(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:188)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.access$600(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:69)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.populate(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:1756)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.populate(JPQLParser.java:56)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.populateFromCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:153)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:658)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:639)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:605)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:667)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.getOperation(QueryImpl.java:1492)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.getOperation(DelegatingQuery.java:123)
 at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:243)
 at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:293)
 at com.XYZ.PQR.bss.client.offering.impl.OfferingServiceImpl.getOfferingsByStringAttribute(OfferingServiceImpl.java:661)
 at com.XYZ.PQR.bss.marker.impl.testAks.testAPI(testAks.java:38)
 at com.XYZ.PQR.bss.marker.impl.testAks.main(testAks.java:24)

    <properties>

<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.XYZ.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
   <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:db2://xyz.com:50000/ABC"/>
   <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="usr"/>
   <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="pwd"/>
   <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="sch123"/>
    <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />

</properties>
```

Comment: Which app server do You use ? I think app wasn't fully deployed becouse ther is no entity in JPA context. Paste full stack trace.

Comment: thanks for replying.I have posted entire stack trace

Comment: Is it standalone application ?

Comment: its a webbase application.But for unit testing i have written a main method.I have made entry in persistent.xml as show above

Answer (score 4):

The first line of the trace warns you that your entities *were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent*.

And while my understanding is that running the enhancer is not is not strictly required, the following part of the trace is still an hint that OpenJPA is not aware of **any entity**:

> Error message: The name "Offeringattribute" is not a recognized entity or identifier. Known entity names: []

It looks like that something went wrong and/or that OpenJPA didn't use any of the [fallback mechanisms](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html#ref_guide_pc_enhance_unenhanced_types). Look for a previous warning in the logs. Or setup build time enhancement.

The following resources might help:

- [Entity Enhancement](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html)
- OpenJPA User's Guide

  - Section [2. Enhancement](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read this very carefuly http://openjpa.apache.org/build-and-runtime-dependencies.html

You have to add geronimo-* libraries to Your project,  if it is stand-alone application.

Comment: i had used the same kind of code to connect to some other database .But am having problem in connecting to this one.Both Databse are DB2.

Comment: is there some problem with persistent.xml.I have pased the configuration of persistent.xml in original post

Comment: First of all use Derby instead of db2 for testing. If you familiar with maven follow  this tutorial http://log.illsley.org/2010/05/15/openjpa-derby-and-getting-started-fast/.

Comment: actually am new to project of my company.The project uses JPA and i have to modify existing cod.No other developer is familiar with JPA and i have 1 day deadline.Actually app JPA apis are developed i need to use those APIs, but those apis are not working i guess some issue with configurations.Looking worward to your help

Comment: I'd have to have your whole environment to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this problem intermittently with a legacy JPA 1.0 web application. It was due to requests occurring to prior to Entity Enhancement.

If any is still stuck with a JPA 1.0 application and is encountering this problem intermittently, try adding the following to `persistence.xml`:

`<property name="openjpa.MetaDataRepository" value="Preload=true" />`

From Open JPA Documentation, Chapter 6.2: [Metadata Repository](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_meta_repository.html):

> **Preload**: A boolean property. If true, OpenJPA will eagerly load the
> repository on EntityManagerFactory creation. As a result, all Entity
> classes will be eagerly loaded by the JVM. Once MetaData preloading
> completes, all locking is removed from the MetaDataRepository and this
> will result in a much more scalable repository. If false, the
> repository will be lazily loaded as Entity classes are loaded by the
> JVM. The default value is false.

This option was not available with `openjpa-1.2.1` (2009), but was introduced by the time `openjpa-1.2.3` was released (2013).